# Can I put a sum into a cell containing text?

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, formulas

I'm creating a spreadsheet in Excel to show the commission structure for our sales team.  The targets will change week by week so I'd like the text in other cells change depending on the target value.

Eg Target = 5
Commission = 23%
Text in other cell = 'When you get [Target+1] your commission will increase by 4%'

Not sure if this can be done or if it would use IF statements or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by using either `=CONCATENATE` or by utilizing ampersands `&` throughout a formula like so:

[image: Excel Screenshot]

The formula in cell `B4` is:

```
="When you get " & B1+1 & " your commission of " & TEXT(B2, "0%") & " will increase by 4%."
```

---

*Note: In this particular case, it would be wise to leverage [Named Ranges](http://www.contextures.com/xlNames01.html) to make the formula more readable and easier to maintain. That is, if we define `B1` to be `Target` and `B2` to be `Commission`, we can change the formula to:*

*`="When you get " & Target+1 & " your commission of " & TEXT(Commission, "0%") & " will increase by 4%."`*